# Setting left to mobile responsive designs in both portrait and landscape

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design, less

I am working in mobile responsive designs in which it will work in both portrait and landscape mobile device.

I have given like below to override the style.

```
@media (max-width: 360px) {
     #footer {
         .dropdown-menu {
               left: 33% !important;
          }
     }

 @media (max-width: 480px) {
     #footer {
         .dropdown-menu {
               left: 27% !important;
          }
     }


@media (max-width: 320px) {
     #footer {
         .dropdown-menu {
               left: 13% !important;
          }
     }
@media (max-width: 767px) {
     #footer {
         .dropdown-menu {
               left: 18% !important;
          }
     }
```

But this is not working, for 320 width, 767 left style is applying.

Please suggest me how to use this to work in mobile device in both portrait and landscape ?

Answer (score 2):

You have to invert the order from the highest width to the lowest like this :

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  #footer {
       .dropdown-menu {
           left: 18%;
       }
  }
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  #footer {
     .dropdown-menu {
           left: 27%;
      }
  }
} 
@media (max-width: 360px) {
  #footer {
     .dropdown-menu {
           left: 33%;
      }
  }
}
@media (max-width: 320px) {
  #footer {
     .dropdown-menu {
           left: 13%;
      }
  }
}
```

Also, I think it's better not to use `!important` to overwrite properties but to play with selectors instead.

Comment: you are using max-width so your case falls in all media queries and in CSS  , last defined rule gets precedence..

Comment: I have used diff values only. Edited now.